# who is that sohabi whose name is mentioned in the quran--majjeed?

Tags: knowing-islam

There are a lot of sohaba-e-ikram in our islam but in the quran no "sohaba" name is mention instead of one "sohaba".

Answer (score 1):

As‘salaamu alaikum.

The Prophet Muhammad‘s (alaihi salaam) adopted son, Zaid ibn Haaritha (radi‘Allahu anhu) is a Companion of the Prophet (a.s.) who is mentioned by name in the Qur‘an, (Surat-ul-Ahzab (33), ayat 37).

To my knowledge, Zaid (r.a.) is the only Companion mentioned by name. Others are alluded to but it is the hadith literature and/or the seerah of the Prophet that tells us explicitly who those ayah are alluding to.

I hope this answer satisfies you.

As‘salaamu alaikum.